# Mining Address get changes very frequently

Tags: private-blockchain, mining, coinbase

I have a private ethereum node running on aws instance, the time when started the node i set the etherbase/coinbase address to the first account of the node. As i started the node i find that first account is getting the rewards of mining and everything was as expected, but after few hours the miner/etherbase address automatically get changed, as a result of which funds from first account get transferred to miner address as a mining reward. And i unlocked the first account to send the transaction over the node and as all the funds get transferred to newly assigned miner address, all my transactions become pending due to insufficient funds in sender account. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Here are the few details of geth client and command i used :

GO ETHEREUM CLIENT DETAILS :
Geth
Version: 1.9.12-stable
Git Commit: b6f1c8dcc058a936955eb8e5766e2962218924bc
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [65 64 63]
Go Version: go1.13.8
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/build/ethereum-YoJS3q/.go

GETH COMMAND :
/usr/bin/geth --datadir node01 --networkid 10 --allow-insecure-unlock --targetgaslimit 9000000000000 --nousb --etherbase '0x669980d2EF6b14e15e4e1D32E70F2ccC83EC98c9' --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3 --rpccorsdomain '*'

GENESIS.JSON :
{
"alloc": {
"0x669980d2EF6b14e15e4e1D32E70F2ccC83EC98c9": {
"balance": "10000000000000000000000000000000000000"
},
"0x61722d9D8F75E97A2F8B4C63Be1C8820D944C940":{
"balance": "1000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
},
"coinbase": "0x669980d2EF6b14e15e4e1D32E70F2ccC83EC98c9",
"config": {
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"byzantiumBlock": 0,
"constantinopleBlock": 0,
"chainId": 10,
"eip150Block": 0,
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"eip158Block": 0,
"maxCodeSize": 35,
"maxCodeSizeChangeBlock" : 0,
"isQuorum": true
},
"difficulty": "0x0",
"extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"gasLimit": "0xE0000000",
"mixhash": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000647572616c65787365646c6578",
"nonce": "0x0",
"parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"timestamp": "0x00"
}

Comment: You are allowing anyone to unlock your accounts and to make arbitrary transfers `--allow-insecure-unlock`. You are enabling administrative commands to run over RPC from remote locations `--rpcapi admin` and your geth instance is opening all internet endpoints to receive RPC commands `--rpcaddr "0.0.0.0"`. I'd suggest to use a firewall to filter valid IPs and only enable p2p 30303.

Comment: @Ismael thanks for the help.  But we are using aws so we can restrict this port for particular ip address, no issue but for just development we have enabled that. No on else  is using our node.  Can you please let me know, can geth create address and assign to coinbase by itself.

Comment: I don't think that is necessary to create a new account, just calling [`miner.setEtherbase`](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-miner#miner_setetherbase) will be enough to change the miner. I don't know how but it is obvious someone is accessing your node and changing the miner address. Increase the geth logging level and watch the output for unexpected behavior.

Comment: Hi @Ismael, We really appreciate you, thanks  

We have also setup a development node and it is still working fine, minor address did not changed a single time but on mainnet node, we are facing this issue.   It is private ether node, why someone change minor address?

Comment: Usually they are bots that check for open RPC ports and then send their commands. They don't care if it is a private network or mainnet. I'd recommend to implement in the firewall a whitelist on the RPC port 8545, or limit access by ssh. Also check go-ethereum security notes from latests releases there was a bug in go runtime https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.9.24.

Comment: @Ismael but how they can get access to my server.  I have one node service also on the same server to interact with eth node and we are using that node service api in multiple application on other server.  in this case, how can they send command to change node mining address.

Comment: If you connect any server to the internet it will immediately get a lots of connections from bots searching for services with open ports. If they find one they will try to exploit it. If you have both geth and app running in the same server you an use IPC directly and disable RPC access.